# How to terminate a particular Azure worker role instance

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

**Background**

I am trying to work out the best structure for an Azure application.  Each of my worker roles will spin up multiple long-running jobs.  Over time I can transfer jobs from one instance to another by switching them to a readonly mode on the source instance, spinning them up on the target instance, and then spinning the original down on the source instance.

If I have too many jobs then I can tell Azure to spin up extra role instance, and use them for new jobs.  Conversely if my load drops (e.g. during the night) then I can consolidate outstanding jobs to a few machines and tell Azure to give me fewer instances.

The trouble is that (as I understand it) Azure provides no mechanism to allow me to decide which instance to stop.  Thus I cannot know which servers to consolidate onto, and some of my jobs will die when their instance stops, causing delays for users while I restart those jobs on surviving instances.

**Idea 1**: I decide which instance to stop, and return from its Run().  I then tell Azure to reduce my instance count by one, and hope it concludes that the broken instance is a good candidate.  Has anyone tried anything like this?

**Idea 2**: I predefine a whole bunch of different worker roles, with identical contents.  I can individually stop and start them by switching their instance count from zero to one, and back again.  I think this idea would work, but I don't like it because it seems to go against the natural Azure way of doing things, and because it involves me in a lot of extra bookkeeping to manage the extra worker roles.

**Idea 3**: Live with it.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your ideas

**Idea 1:**  I haven't tried doing exactly what you're describing, but in my experience your first instance has a name that ends with _0,  the next _1 and I'm sure you can guess the rest.  When you decrease the instance count it drops off the instance with the highest number suffix.  I would be surprised if it took into account the state of any particular instance.

**Idea 2:**  As I think you hint at, this will create management problems.  You can only have 5 different workers per hosted service, so you'll need a service for each group of 5 roles that you want to be able to scale to.  Also when you deploy updates you'll have to upload X times more services where X is the maximum number of instances you currently support.

**Idea 3:**  Technically the easiest.  Pending some clarification, this is probably what I'd be doing for now.  To reduce the downsides of this option it may pay to investigate ways of loading the data faster.  There is usually a Goldilocks level (not too much, not too little) of parallelism that helps with this.

Comment: re Idea 1: That is very useful information.  Being able to predict which will go is almost as good as being able to specify.

Comment: re Idea 3: I hope to improve load times eventually, but it is a complicated, pre-existing program so I cannot rely on this for the first rollout.

Comment: You cannot count on idea #1 - there is absolutely no guarantee which instance will be terminated when scaling from, say, 3 instances to 2.

Regarding idea #3 - if your jobs are triggered by a queue message, and if your queue-processing output is idempotent, you don't have to worry about an instance being shut down - the in-progress queue items will simply be made visible in the queue again (after your preset timeout value) and another instance will reprocess it.

Answer (score 1):

You're right - you cannot choose which instance to stop. In general, you'd run the same jobs on each worker role instance, where each instance watches the same queue (or maybe multiple threads or jobs watching multiple queues).

If you really need to run a job on one instance (such as a scheduler), consider using blob leases as the way to constrain this. Create a blob as a mutex. Then, as each instance spins up, the scheduler job attempts to obtain a write lease on that blob. If it succeeds, it runs. If it fails, it simply sleeps (maybe for a minute) and tries again. At some point in the future, as you scale down in instance count, let's say the instance running the scheduler is killed. A minute later (or whatever time span you choose), another instance tries to acquire the lease, succeeds, and now runs the scheduler code.

Comment: I should have explained that each "job" (a simplification - it is actually loading a large data file and querying it for users) takes minutes to start and uses about 50MB of RAM, but answers multiple job-related requests very quickly.  Therefore I want to start each job on a single role instance, but squeeze as many jobs onto each instance as I can.  I have one message queue per job, so if a job is restarted nothing will be lost, but it gives the user an undesirable delay.  Knowing in advance which jobs to move to another host lets me minimize disruption (see original question).